# Как правильно типизировать данные, приходящие с клиента на сервер?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

Например что бы при вводе `req.body` всплывали значения описанные в типе или интерфейсе

```
exports.login = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const newUser: SignUpformType = {
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword
  }
}
```

Comment: Указать правильный тип, вместо `req: Request`

Comment: `const body: MyBodyType = req.body as MyBodyType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Устанавливаем определения

> yarn add @types/express

И описываем роутер как в интерфейсе [IRouterMatcher](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L65)

```
import * as express from 'express';

interface SignUpformType {
    username: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    confirmPassword: string;
};

const fun: express.RequestHandler<Record<string, any>, any, SignUpformType, any> = (req, res) => {
    const newUser: SignUpformType = req.body;
    res.send('Hello World!');
};

const app: express.Application = express();

app.get<any, string, SignUpformType>('/', (req, res) => {
    const newUser: SignUpformType = req.body;
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.get('/test', fun);

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log(`App is listening on port 3000!`);
});
```